# Removing duplicates from a QList

Tags: c++, qt

For years I have been using the following pattern to remove duplicates from an object of the C++ `std::vector` type:

```
std::vector<int> cont;
std::sort(cont.begin(), cont.end());
cont.erase(std::unique(cont.begin(), cont.end()), cont.end());
```

Now I am wondering if the same paradigm is the one to be used with the Qt `QList<>` class, or if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: As you are dealing with lists, I want to point out that std::list has a member sort function which has better performance than std::sort on a list.

Comment: and yes just rediscovered, std::list also has 'unique' member function which means it is preferable over std::unique.

Comment: Thanks Amit for pointing this out, but I do not use std::list<> much (following Herb Sutter's advice that std::vector is in most cases the "right" container to use; even in the C++ standard there is such a recommendation, see 23.1.1/2).

Comment: Herb Sutter (and others) advice that std::vector is in most cases the correct container to use if all you need is a container.  However, if you want a *sorted, unique* collection of items, they would almost certainly recommend a container that gives you those aspects by default, rather than using the most generic container you can and adding them on yourself.

Comment: I agree that if you want a sorted unique collection and that is all you care about, std::set<> is great and for a long time I would consider no other way. But bitter experience taught me that such solutions do not necessarily scale well -- the performance goes down if the number of elements goes up, if you use associative containers without realizing their drawbacks. To illustrate: if you need to build a sorted container to be used only for reading but not modifying it, it is much cheaper to build the `std::vector` and sort it just once.

Comment: @VladoKlimovský Please, accept this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41128125/6941952) because it's more general. I have had the same problem and this answer helped me. However, the accepted answer didn't.

Comment: This code in the question, as posted, works perfectly with QList. There's a major source of confusion in the comments above, and it has to do with thinking that QList is a linked list (like std::list). It's not. QList is an array-backed container, similar to std::vector. Do not do expensive conversions through QSet when algorithms work just fine!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know about performance, but what about converting the `QList` into a `QSet` ?

```
QList<int> myQList;
//...
QSet<int> = QSet::fromList(myQList);
// or
QSet<int> = myQList.toSet();
```

(and maybe convert it back to a `QList` if needed with [QList::fromSet()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#fromSet))

Comment: That _is_ a way, for sure, but then I would use QSet<> directly. I usually prefer sequential containers (which are most of the time the most appropriate choice), so QSet<> or std::set can be considered an overkill.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste : if I need to store a list of elements without duplicates, I always choose a set. I never compared the performance though.

Comment: Well, I used to use the `std::set` or `std::map` a lot, until I had to fight with performance issues. Now I think twice before going that way ;-).

Comment: Note that this solution only works for types that have the qHash function override for them. Also, QStringList has a removeDuplicates() function (see http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtcore/qstringlist.html#removeDuplicates)

Comment: You can also write it like this: `itemList = itemList.toSet().toList();`

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot be used if you want to preserve the order of the original list.

Comment: Please, do NOT do this! The code in the original question (`std::sort` + `std::unique`) is exactly the code that works on QList and QVector. QList is not a linked list.

Comment: And, side note, .toSet() and friends are getting deprecated/removed between Qt 5.15 and Qt 6.0.

Answer (score 7):

If you are creating this list:

Then **avoiding duplicates** may be a viable alternative to removing duplicates.

```
QList<int> cont;
int incomingValue;
if(!cont.contains(incomingValue))
{
    cont.append(incomingValue);
}
```

Additionally, Since this is a question about QList< > (and not only QList< int >)...

Some may be using a custom class, and like to avoid duplicates.

```
class SoftDrink
{
public:
    int oz
    QString flavor
    bool operator==(const Beverage &other) const{
        uint hash = qHash(flavor) ^ oz;
        uint otherHash = qHash(other.flavor) ^ other.oz;
        return hash == otherHash;
    }
}
```

an **== operator** like the one above can allow QList to evaluate the contains() method against a custom datatype

```
QList<SoftDrink> uniquePurchaseHistory;
SoftDrink newPurchase;
if(!uniquePurchaseHistory.contains(newPurchase)){
    uniquePurchaseHistory.append(newPurchase);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without Warranty:

With QVector it seems to work ...

```
QVector<int> v;
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end() );

v.erase( std::unique(v.begin(), v.end() ), v.end() );//remove duplicates
```

From Vector back to list:

```
QVector<QString> vect;
vect << "red" << "green" << "blue" << "black";

QList<QString> list = vect.toList();
// list: ["red", "green", "blue", "black"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's the `QList<QString>`, you can give the [QStringList::removeDuplicates()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringlist.html#removeDuplicates) a try.

```
    QStringList newLst = orgLst;
    newLst.removeDuplicates();
```